# How to rename a file using inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I want to first rename an existing file 'My program old' to 'My program v2' but only if 'My program v2' doesn't already exist.

Then I want to rename 'My program' to 'My program old' but only if 'My program old' doesn't already exist.

And then I want to install 'My program' from the installer but only if 'My program' doesn't already exist.

I would be very grateful for any guidance !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would give a try to something like this. In the `ssInstall` stage of the [`CurStepChanged`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged) event, which occurs just before the installation process starts, just check if the file doesn't exist with the [`FileExists`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_fileexists) function, and if not, then just call the [`RenameFile`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_renamefile) function, which will silently fail if the source file doesn't exist, so you don't need to care if the source file exists. In the [`[Files]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection) section you can then use the [`onlyifdoesntexist`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=onlyifdoesntexist) flag for your last requirement. You can follow the [`commented version`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13071561/4) of this script if you want:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Files]
Source: "My program"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist

[Code]
function GetFileName(const AFileName: string): string;
begin
  Result := ExpandConstant('{app}\' + AFileName);
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if (CurStep = ssInstall) then
  begin
    if not FileExists(GetFileName('My program v2')) then
      RenameFile(GetFileName('My program old'), GetFileName('My program v2'));
    if not FileExists(GetFileName('My program old')) then
      RenameFile(GetFileName('My program'), GetFileName('My program old'));
  end;
end;
```